# Bulk updating text

Tags: regex, awk, sed, notepad++

I have some records, like so:

```
192.168.0.1 example1.domain.com
192.168.0.2 example2.domain.com
192.168.0.3 example3.domain.com
```

This is of course dummy data and would vary, but the format would remain the same.

I'm looking for a way to convert them (in bulk) to look like this:

```
1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa 3600 IN PTR example1.domain.com
2.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa 3600 IN PTR example2.domain.com
3.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa 3600 IN PTR example3.domain.com
```

Any solution will do, whether that be using Notepad++ regex, sed, awk, etc.

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code on your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`.

```
awk '{split($1,a,"."); 
     print(a[4]"."a[3]"."a[2]"."a[1]".in-addr.arpa 3600 IN PTR",$2)}' file
```

Output:

```
1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa 3600 IN PTR example1.domain.com
2.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa 3600 IN PTR example2.domain.com
3.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa 3600 IN PTR example3.domain.com
```

Comment: Try it with notepad++  ..... Find: `^(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d\.\d+) (.*)`  ..... Replace with: `$3$2$1in-addr.arpa 3600 IN PTR $4`